# Flutter Flame using two Camera Components and hide a Component inside a World Component form one Camera

Tags: flutter, camera, flame

In the game, two CameraComponents are employed. One camera is used for the actual gameplay, while the other serves the purpose of displaying a minimap to the player. Both cameras utilize the same World component. The objective is to display a target on the minimap at specific coordinates without it being visible in the first camera.

The only method that comes to mind is to have two separate worlds. Is that the only approach? Unfortunately, you cannot hide a component in front of a CameraComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to override the render method of the component that you don't want to render and check which camera it is that is rendering it, so it would be something like this:

```dart
@override
void render(Canvas canvas) {
  if(CameraComponent.currentCamera == theCameraYouDontWantToRender) {
    return;
  }
  ...
  super.render(canvas);
}
```